# Opening link on button click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, triggers, click

Below is the code am trying,

```
$('#Btn1').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
    url:"upload.php",
    data:{
            base64: data
        },
    type:"post",
    success: function(response){
        $("#link1").attr("href", urlToOpen);
        $("#link1").focus();
        $("#link1").click();
    },
    error: function(){}
});
}
```

And the link element in html page is,

```
<a id="link1" target="_blank">Trigger Me...</a>
```

Is there any problem with this code? This is not working in mobile devices also.

Comment: ,are you trying to call the function on anchor click

Comment: click function not closed `});`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @user3040610  No, am not trying with anchor.

Comment: @prasad Just missed it while copying.

Comment: No error at console @Rejith R Krishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the JavaScript `click()`, like following.

```
$("#link1").attr("href", urlToOpen);
$("#link1")[0].click();
```

Comment: The problem facing in this case is, it acting like window.open(). It is different from touching directly on that link wit static href. Am triggering an application through that link.

Comment: @Nidhish so, the link is not used to open a new window?